# Не корректный просчет теней от point light

Tags: unity3d

При приближении источника света (point light) к любому объекту на нем появляется квадратный "засвет". Я так понимаю эта проблема связанна с параметром Near Plane, если я его ставлю в значение 1.6 или более, то "засвет" пропадает, но в таком случае тени от объектов в некотором радиусе не отображаются, есть-ли способ сохранить тени и убрать "засвет"?
[image: Пример "засвета"]
[image: Параметры point light]

Comment: `Far Plane` большой?

Comment: Такого параметра у point light нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я увеличил параметр Bias до 0.032, и "засвет" исчез.